# How to store and retrieve average number value from parse object?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I use parse api in my android app. I'd like to store number value in parse object which represents average user ratings. I can use this forumula to put all necessary data into parse object:

save data to parse object:

```
ParseObject.increment("num_rating");
ParseObject.increment("rating", 5);
```

get object average rating:

```
Number averageRating = ParseObject.get("rating")/ParseObject.get("num_rating");
```

but this solution doesn't let me query parse objects by average rating. Is there any way I can store average value in parse object and retrive it using parse query?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, after you increment them, run your query to get the average and then store that in another column.

Comment: I can't do that. It would overwrite global average value, because there is a time gap between getting and saving value. Other users may also save their score in this time.

Comment: Then put the calculation in a beforeSave event in cloud code.